# Templatized GLib asynchronous queue

Tags: c++, asynchronous, queue, template-meta-programming, glib

I'm working on a legacy C++ project, which is using GLib for its Main Event Loop. This has caused a lot of ugliness because it mixes C++ and C paradigms (no C++ wrapper for GLib had been used).

Anyway, I'd like to generalize some classes that internally use the [Asynchronous Queue](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) provided by GLib.

This is what I've done:

```
// File AsyncQueue.h - C++11 required 
#include "glib.h"

template<typename T>
class AsyncQueue
{
    static gboolean prepare(GSource *source, gint *timeout)
    {
        auto async_queue_source = reinterpret_cast<AsyncQueueSource*>(source);

        if( nullptr == async_queue_source || nullptr == async_queue_source->async_queue )
            return FALSE;

        if( nullptr != timeout )
            *timeout = -1; // Poll timeout

        return g_async_queue_length(async_queue_source->async_queue) > 0;
    }

    static gboolean check(GSource *source)
    {
        auto async_queue_source = reinterpret_cast<AsyncQueueSource*>(source);

        if( nullptr == async_queue_source || nullptr == async_queue_source->async_queue )
            return FALSE;

        return g_async_queue_length(async_queue_source->async_queue) > 0;
    }

    static gboolean dispatch(GSource *source, GSourceFunc callback, gpointer user_data)
    {
        auto async_queue_source = reinterpret_cast<AsyncQueueSource*>(source);

        if( nullptr == async_queue_source || nullptr == async_queue_source->async_queue )
            return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;

        auto item = reinterpret_cast<T*>(g_async_queue_pop(async_queue_source->async_queue));

        if( nullptr != item )
        {
            if( nullptr != async_queue_source->this_object )
                async_queue_source->this_object->OnItemPopped(*item);
            delete item;
        }

        return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
    }

    struct AsyncQueueSource
    {
        GSource        source_object;
        AsyncQueue<T>* this_object;
        GAsyncQueue*   async_queue;
    };

    static_assert(std::is_trivial<AsyncQueueSource>::value, "AsyncQueueSource must be a trivial type");

    GSourceFuncs source_funcs;
    GMainContext* context;
    guint source_id_within_context;
    AsyncQueueSource* async_queue_source;

public:
    // noncopyable
    AsyncQueue(const AsyncQueue&) = delete;
    AsyncQueue& operator=(const AsyncQueue&) = delete;

    AsyncQueue()
        : source_funcs{&AsyncQueue::prepare, nullptr, &AsyncQueue::dispatch, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr}
        , context{nullptr}
        , source_id_within_context{0}
    {
        async_queue_source = reinterpret_cast<AsyncQueueSource*>(g_source_new(&source_funcs, sizeof(AsyncQueueSource)));

        if( nullptr != async_queue_source )
        {
            async_queue_source->this_object = this;
            async_queue_source->async_queue = g_async_queue_new();
        }
    }

    virtual ~AsyncQueue()
    {
        if( nullptr != async_queue_source )
        {
            if( nullptr != async_queue_source->async_queue )
            {
                g_async_queue_unref(async_queue_source->async_queue);
            }
            async_queue_source->this_object = nullptr;
            g_source_unref(reinterpret_cast<GSource*>(async_queue_source));
        }
    }

    bool Attach(GMainContext* main_context)
    {
        bool result = false;

        if( nullptr != async_queue_source )
        {
            source_id_within_context = g_source_attach(&async_queue_source->source_object, main_context);
            if( source_id_within_context > 0 )
                result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    bool IsAttached() const { return source_id_within_context > 0; }

    virtual void OnItemPopped(T& item) = 0;

    // item must be allocated with new() and will be owned by AsyncQueue
    void PushItem(T* item)
    {
        if( nullptr != item )
        {
            if( nullptr != async_queue_source && nullptr != async_queue_source->async_queue )
            {
                g_async_queue_push(async_queue_source->async_queue, item);
                if( IsAttached() )
                    g_main_context_wakeup(context);
            }
            else
            {
                delete item;
            }
        }
    }

    void PushItem(const T* item)
    {
        if( nullptr != item )
        {
            auto copied_item = new T(*item);
            PushItem(copied_item);
        }
    }

    void PushItem(const T& item)
    {
        auto copied_item = new T(item);
        PushItem(copied_item);
    }

    void PushItem(T&& item)
    {
        auto moved_item = new T(std::move(item));
        PushItem(moved_item);
    }
};
```

**Pointer misuse**

This class seems reasonably clean and simple to use, but my main concern is misuse of `AsyncQueue::PushItem(T* item)` because the caller could pass a pointer to an object on the heap or something allocated with `g_new` or `malloc`.

I could give the responsibility to free the memory to the implementer of `virtual void OnItemPopped(T& item)` by passing a T* instead, but I don't like this option.

What if I accept only smart pointers of type `std::unique_ptr<T>` and therefore I change signatures as `AsyncQueue::PushItem(std::unique_ptr<T> item)` and `virtual void OnItemPopped(std::unique_ptr<T> item)`? Anyway, I would still have to pass naked pointers to the asynchronous queue because it works only with trivial types (aka POD types).

**Thread safety**

Multiple threads should be able to call without issues `AsyncQueue::PushItem`, all the synchronization is done by GLib inside the async queue. The only thread able to pop elements is the thread running the Main Loop on the GMainContext passed to `AsyncQueue::Attach`.

Besides this, there are some obvious multithreading flaws that I missed?

**Items leaked on class destruction**

If the class or the main loop is destroyed when the queue still holds data they will be leaked (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52175388/297373). I'm not sure how to solve this issue.